# Apply common custom authentication functionality to multiple Flask projects

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I've created a class which authenticates users based on our company's user server.  I'd like to apply it to any of our Flask apps which use Flask-Login rather than repeating the code in each project.  I'm not sure what the right pattern for this is, or how to implement it.

I thought of a few options:

1. Python module - simply authentication, the module would do the login then return something (maybe credentials or token).
2. Flask 'app' - authenticates, includes a login and logout screen, and somehow gets linked in with `@login_manager.user_loader`. The issue I see is that the user loaded could have any application's User schema.

What is a good pattern for implementing this common authentication for multiple projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the common functions of setting up a Flask-Login manger and the custom login views/functions you need to a simple Flask extension package.  Install this package with `pip` in the environment of each project and use it when creating that project's Flask app.

`company_auth/company_auth.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, url_for, render_template
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_wtf import Form

bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

class LoginForm(Form):
    # define your login form

@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # do custom login stuff
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('auth/login.html', form=form)

def init_app(app, user_model):
    # have to pass in the user model since it's different between apps

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def company_user_loader(id):
        user = user_model.query.get(id)
        # do custom user loading stuff
        return user

    app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/auth')
```

`company_auth/setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='company_auth',
    version='1.0',
    py_modules=['company_auth'],
    url='http://davidism.com/',
    license='BSD',
    author='davidism',
    author_email='davidism@gmail.com',
    description='Flask extension for company auth',
    requires=['flask']
)
```

Create a distribution of the package to install in other projects.

```
$ python setup.py sdist
```

For each project, install the package, import and run the `init_app` function, and provide the auth templates. (Your extension could include default templates too, but this answer would get gigantic if I go down that path.  See [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) for an example of default templates.)

```
$ project_env/bin/activate
$ pip install /path/to/company_auth/dist/company_auth-1.0.tar.gz
```

Create the auth templates:

```
project/
    templates/
        auth/
            login.html
    app.py
```

Set up the app with the custom auth:

```
import company_auth
company_auth.init_app()
```